# How to get a DI instance object, or inject a property, with a parameterless classes in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to create a custom `TagHelper` and not being able to get an instance of `IApplicationEnvironment`, once the `TagHelper` base class just have a parameterless constructor.

So, what is the way to inject a property, or create an instance, for the DI?

Answer (score 0):

I found it. We can use `[Activate]` attribute from `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc`.

```
namespace ActivatorWebSite.TagHelpers
{
    [TargetElement("body")]
    public class FooterTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        [Activate] // here
        IApplicationEnvironment ApplicationEnvironment { get; set; }

        [Activate] // and here
        public IHtmlHelper HtmlHelper { get; set; }

        [Activate] // and here
        public ViewDataDictionary ViewData { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.PostContent.SetContent($"<footer>{HtmlHelper.Encode(ViewData["footer"])}</footer>");
        }
    }
}
```